# jQuery sliding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have three image buttons and once I click on one of them a sliding div containing text appears.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showSlidingDiv() {
        $("#slidingDiv").animate({
            "height": "toggle"
        }, {
            duration: 300
        })
    }
    function showSlidingDiv2() {
        $("#slidingDiv2").animate({
            "height": "toggle"
        }, {
            duration: 300
        })
    }
    function showSlidingDiv3() {
        $("#slidingDiv2").animate({
            "height": "toggle"
        }, {
            duration: 300
        })
    }
    </script>
```

The function is triggered with this command:

```
    <a href="#" onClick="showSlidingDiv(); return false;">
```

The script works fine but currently if I click all the links the content appends to each other - what I would like to achieve is to hide an open div class once I click on a new link.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jQuery [accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) plugin.

**Update:**
You can close all divs and open the one selected:

```
    function toggleDiv(selectedDiv) {
      // shortcut to select all sliding divs
      $('div[id^="sliding"]').animate({
              "height": "toggle"
          }, {
              duration: 300
          }, function () {
                $(selectedDiv).show();
      });
              }
```

In your hrefs, call the function like this:

```
onClick="toggleDiv('#slidingDiv1'); // use slidingDiv2, 3 for other hrefs
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - but I like the current solution - is there a way to have other open divs hidden / closed if I click on a new one?